# Object transfer using sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, real-time

```
    if(server&&network){
    try{
       serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
       socket = serverSocket.accept();
       System.out.println("Connected to " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
       out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
       in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
       out.writeObject(lou);
       out.flush();
       out.reset();
       out.writeObject(dud);
       out.flush();
       out.reset();
       me = new Gen(lou, dud);
       //socket.close();
       //serverSocket.close();
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
    }else if(network&&!server){
        try{
             //Socket socket = new Socket("10.69.18.244", 12345);
             socket = new Socket("192.168.1.100", 12345);
             //Socket socket = new Socket("10.69.18.162", 12345);
             out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
             in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
             lou = (ArrayList)in.readObject();
             //in.reset();
             dud = (ArrayList)in.readObject();
             //in.reset();
             me = new Gen(dud, lou);
             //socket.close();
        }catch(Exception ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try to use `out.writeobject(lou)` on the server. The client throws a `NotSerializableException`. I have no idea why because I'm initializing it right above it.

Comment: Correct terminology please. 'Real-time' has a specific meaning in computing, and this isn't it. Do you mean something like 'real-world'? Or 'timely'?

Answer (score 0):

You want to open one connection and keep it open for the whole game.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do. The code I posted is what I thought I would have to do every loop keeping the connection open. But it threw some errors

Comment: @user2054739 - am i supposed to guess which errors?  hint, when trying to get help, don't start with what you think the answer is, start with the _actual_ problem and include _all_ the relevant details.

Comment: @user2054739 - making a wild guess based on the small bit of code you included, the `in.reset()` is causing problems.  i'd suggest reading the javadoc on that method because it doesn't do what you think it's doing.

Comment: @user2054739 - additionally, don't swallow exceptions, it leaves your program in a broken state.